# The complex heat kernel on a Riemann manifold

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, laplacian, schrodinger-operators, heat-equation

There is a vast literature available for the heat kernel. Nevertheless, I haven't been able to find almost anything useful about the kernel of the equation $\frac{1}{\mathbb{i}} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \Delta u =0$. So far, I have three questions about it:

1) if $e(t,x,y)$ is the above kernel, is it bounded in $x$ (in $\mathbb{R}^n$ it is)?

2) since $e$ is not real, it is impossible to construct a Gaussian probability starting from it; what, then, can still be done? I assume one can still construct a complex measure, but what are its "nice" properties?

3) finally, do you know of any rich monography on the subject? I have found plenty of titles about the "usual" heat kernel, yet none regarding my question - which I find strange given how important the Schrödinger equation is.

Comment: Here's a bunch of links: http://www.amazon.com/The-Mehler-Kernel-Erwin-Kronberger/dp/3639241193
$$\ \ \ $$
https://www.google.com/search?q=mehler+kernel&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the term "Mehler Kernel" is used for the integral kernel of the heat equation corresponding the the harmonic oscillator,
$$ \partial_tu + \Delta u + x^2 u = 0.$$
The equation you are talking about is the *Schrödinger equation*. The kernel on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is 
$$ e_t(x, y) = (4\pi i t)^{-n/2} e^{-\frac{1}{4 i t} |x-y|^2},$$
that is the heat kernel with imaginary values plugged in for $t$. Despite the the formal similarity to the heat kernel, it has vastly different properties: For example, the integral
$$u(t, x) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e_t(x, y) u(y) \mathrm{d} y$$
does not converge absolutely for arbitrary functions in $L^2$, and it is not smoothing in the sense that it maps distributions to smooth functions. However, it preserves smoothness.

In particular, it does *not* define a complex $\sigma$-aditive measure!

On manifolds, this gets way worse: For example, I know from some corner of my memory that on the sphere, it is not smooth at all; instead, it is a singular distribution at every point at most times.

Comment: Are you sure about the non-smoothness of $e$? Isn't the operator $\frac{1} {\mathbb{i}} \frac{\partial} {\partial t} - \Delta$  hypoelliptic?

Comment: No, why would it be?

Comment: Given that the (usual) heat operator is, I was expecting the complex one to be so, too. Do you have any knowledge on $z \frac{\partial} {\partial t} - \Delta$, with $z \in \mathbb{C}, z \neq 0$? I assume some discussion on the sign of $\mathbb{Re} \space z$ is necessary. I'm a little lost, it's the first time I stumble upon these questions.

Comment: Depending on the sign conventions, $z$ may be in either the left or the right half plane to make the operator still hypoelliptic. For $z$ on the imaginary axis (the "boundary case"), it never hypoelliptic. You can easily verify this on $S^1$ by Fourier transform for example.

Comment: Thank you for all this useful information. Could you give me some bibliographic hints, please? You must have found all these results somewhere, for sure, and it is exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but where can I find the result on the non-smoothness of the kernel of the Schrödinger equation on the sphere?

Comment: I don't know any "real" references, just posts like http://mathoverflow.net/questions/114492/propagation-of-singularities-the-schrodinger-equation/114538#114538 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/114492/propagation-of-singularities-the-schrodinger-equation/114538#114538

Comment: Thank you. Please note that you gave me the same link twice. Is this what you really meant?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275830/schr%C3%B6dinger-kernels-on-manifolds