# Propagation of singularities and the Schrodinger equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, micro-local-analysis

I always thought that the propagation of singularities theorem by Hörmander says (on $\mathbb R^n$ for a classical symbol $p(x,\xi)=\xi^2+V(x)$) that for a Schrödinger equation
$$(i \partial_t-p(x,D))u=0$$ 
$$u(0)=u_0$$

the wavefront set of $WF(u(t))$ is given by $WF(u_0)$ under the Hamiltonian flow determined by the Hamilton function $p(x,\xi).$

However, now I finally looked at the statement of the theorem

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485889724

on page 14 of the pdf and cannot see that this is the same as I thought it was as apparently the wavefront set of $WF(u(t))$ is only a subset of the wavefront set of $WF(u_0)$ under the Hamiltonian flow.

Question 1: Am I interpreting this correct?

Question 2: So if $u_0$ has for example empty singular support, won't this necessarily be the case for $u(t)$ as well?

Question 3: What confuses me most though is that he denotes the Hamiltonian vector field as something that only depends on the principal part $p$, i.e. $p= \left\lvert \xi \right\rvert^2.$ So apparently the Hamiltonian vector field does not depend on the potential if $p(x,\xi)=\xi^2+V(x).$

Comment: A naive application of Hörmander's theorem on the propagation of singularities doesn't tell you much in this case. The principal symbol (just $\xi^2$) doesn't give you the flow that you naively expect because of the imbalance between the order of the time (first order) and space (second order) derivatives. A related question, specifically about the Schroedinger equation, was asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/114492). And some relevant references are given there.